# Compiling a C++ library in Windows for Linux on Intel

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, compilation, cross-compiling

Need to run the library OpenCV on a linux-based device (a Rexroth XM21).
This one has an Intel Atom 32bit CPU.
Would it be possible to compile the library for that device on Windows (also running on an Intel platform)?
I have the sources to actually compile a windows DLL but that one cannot be used directly of course.

I already had bad experiences when I compiled it on a Raspberry Pi (ARM). Sadly the .so file from the Raspberry quits with an error due to the architecture incompatibility.

So is there any solution?
Some sort of cross-compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a regular gcc build on Ubuntu for example. The easiest way is to install an Ubuntu ISO on a VirtualBox machine, if you don't have a native Linux machine available. The Intel Atom CPU should be compatible to the CPU of your PC. There are things that can get into your way though, for example if the target linux system uses an older version of libc. Doesn't the manufacturer provide a dedicated cross toolchain for the device?

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Will try to compile it on a fresh linux system here. Can it be an issue that the Atom is 32 bit and my systems are 64 bit?
There are some files in the download section here: http://www.boschrexroth.com/dcc/Vornavigation/Vornavi.cfm?Language=EN&Variant=internet&VHist=g257180&PageID=p650745
Is that what's required for the toolchain?

Comment: Just received the information that actually running linux at all on this device is entirely experimental, so there's no toolchain or anything.

Comment: Yeah, you should install a 32-bit Ubuntu. The download section doesn't seem to provide a cross-toolchain. If your target was an ARM system I would have proposed to use a linaro cross toolchain. Unfortunately Linaro doesn't provide toolchains for x86 (e.g. atom) systems. So I would try a build from a 32-bit Ubuntu system. If it isn't compatible you may have to install an older Ubuntu image and try with that for compatible libc versions.

Comment: Ok, but you can access it via SSH? So you can find out about the OS version using 'uname -a'.

Comment: It is a debian derivate apparently: Linux xm21-debian 4.1.5-rt5-xm21-bluetooth #15 PREEMPT RT Thu Sep 17 11:02:25 CEST 2015 i686 GNU/Linux
  I've used the command here to determine the clib version and it's 2.19. Is that somewhat actual?

Comment: That's the same as on a Ubuntu 14.04 system. You could give it a try.